# Grep not working in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble understanding why my grep function in R is not working.  I think this has something to do with the data type of my check word and my keyword list.  Here is my output:

```
> check
[1] "DESIRE"
> delwords
          delete
1        INITIAL
2    DELIVERABL
3    DEMONSTRAT
4         DESIR
5        DESIRE
> grep(check,delwords)
integer(0)
> typeof(check)
[1] "character"
> typeof(delwords)
[1] "list"
```

Comment: Try `grep(check, delwords$delete)`

Comment: Great, akrun's suggestion worked!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me *delwords* here is actually **data.frame**.  Please try to see what is class of delwords.  It should be list, not data.frame

```
class(delwords)
```

Also, I have created this sample :

```
check  = "DESIRE"
delwords = list("INITIAL","DELIVERABL","DEMONSTRAT","DESIR","DESIRE")

grep(check,delwords)
```

and it seems it is working correctly:

```
[1] 5
```

Comment: or a `character` vector; @akrun has the right solution for the question as posted above

Comment: Yea his worked for me, I'm not sure I get the difference between class(object) and typeof(object)?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out be @grubjesic, the form of output that you posted of `delwords` suggests that

```
> class(delwords)
[1] "data.frame"
```

If this is the case, then the solution presented in a comment by @akrun works:

```
> grep(check,delwords$delete)
[1] 5
```

Alternatively, if you don't necessarily need to use grep, you can obtain the same result with

```
> which(delwords$delete==check)
[1] 5
```

And, as a final test, you may try:

```
> delwords[grep(check,delwords$delete),]
[1] DESIRE
Levels: DELIVERABL DEMONSTRAT DESIR DESIRE INITIAL
```

In this post I only expanded on the suggestions by @akrun and @grubjesic. They deserve the credits. The sole purpose of this post is to provide some further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative methods, as there are definitely instances where I will need the other suggestions!